# php empty post variable

Tags: php, forms, post

ti want to submit a form using post method but my code doesn't work i can't find what's  wrong with this code it should ouput the value of the input but it still outputting error every time

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
    $nom = $_POST["nom"];

    echo $nom;
}else echo "error";


?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="POST">
        <h3>Submit a Link</h3>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Nom complet :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom complet"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="send"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share with us what you have tried or researched. Right now this looks like "Please debug my code", which is off topic.

Comment: Your submit button doesn't have a name.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">`

Comment: yeah i see sorry i've been using ajax to submit my forms and now i forgot the basic way so funny

Comment: `senior dev` and such kind ov mistakes ... you are fired

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  

}
```

simply try

```
if(!empty($_POST)){  

}
```

Because you don't have any fields with the name "submit".

Comment: $_POST is always set, even when there is no form submission. There is no point to check if $_POST is set...

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<td></td><td><input type="submit" value="send"></td>
```

To this line:

```
<td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"></td>
```

The problem was that you did not define the name attribute.